# Telerik RadAysncUpload Select button is not visible in Compatibility View

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-radinput

In my Telerik RadAsyncupload, when i switched to Compatbile view [IE8] "Select" button is not visible.

I tried to find the solution but the only update that i got is

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-select-button-not-visible.html

Above solution didnt worked for me.

Any help!!

Comment: Have you tried to set the EnableFileInputSkinning property to false?

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
 <telerik:radupload id="RadUpload1" runat="server" enablefileinputskinning="true"
    inputsize="50" width="475px" ></telerik:radupload>
```

it might help you